# I am decrypting files in gnupg but they are being written as empty

Tags: python, gnupg

This script is supposed to download gpg files off an sftp server, copy them to the local windows dir, back up the encrypted files, and decrypt the files to their own directory.
Everything is working except that the decrypted files that are created are always empty.

```
import pysftp
import gnupg #dycription
import os

############## Decryption variables
KeyPath=(r"C:\winuser\test\key"+slash)
KeyFile=(r"C:\winuser\test\sbp.asc")
DecryptedPath=(r"C:\winuser\test\Deycrpt"+slash)
SourcPath=(r"C:\winuser\test"+slash)
ArchivePath=(r"C:\winuser\test"+slash)

def ConnectSFTP(server, port, username, password, cnopts):

def DownloadSFTP(RemotePath, end, LocalPath,newsftp):

def decrypt(KeyPath, KeyFile, DecryptedPath, SourcePath, ArchivePath, ls):
    gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=KeyPath)
    gpg.import_keys(open(KeyFile).read())
    for f in ls:
        with open(SourcePath+f, 'rb') as fh:
            status = gpg.decrypt_file(fh, output=f[:-4])
        outfile = DecryptedPath+f[:-4]
        with open(outfile,"wb") as fo:
            fo.write(status.data)
        #os.rename(DecryptedPath+f[:-4], DecryptedPath+f[:-4]+status.extension)
        os.rename(SourcePath+f, ArchivePath+f)
    return True
        
            
    

with ConnectSFTP(host, port, username, password, cnopts) as newsftp:
    ls = DownloadSFTP(RemotePath, end,LocalPath,newsftp)

decrypt(KeyPath, KeyFile, DecryptedPath, SourcPath, ArchivePath, ls)
    

print(ls)
```

the only thing I can think of is that I am not writing to the files. Being new to python I am a little befuddled as to how I am ducking it up.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So what do you get with the lie ```status = gpg.decrypt_file(fh, output=f[:-4])```?

Comment: a print of status is showing nothing

Comment: a print of fh is <_io.BufferedReader name='C:\\Users\\person\\test.py.gpg'>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, yup I was being dumb.
Needed gnupghome to point to the gnuphome exe and remove the file creation stuff

'def decrypt(HomePath, KeyFile, DecryptedPath, SourcePath, ArchivePath, ls):
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=HomePath)
gpg.import_keys(open(KeyFile).read())
for f in ls:
with open(SourcePath+f, 'rb') as fh:
status = gpg.decrypt_file(fh, output=DecryptedPath+ f[:-4])
os.rename(SourcePath+f, ArchivePath+f)
return True'

Comment: This answer could use some formatting